# How do you include a global class in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to include a class for every controller to use. Here is what I tried with no luck.

In the Controller.php file, I added this line of code:

```
use App\Lib\RequestType;
```

Then in my controller UserController.php, I called a test function.

```
dd(RequestType::test());
```

But a fatal error is thrown.

**Class 'App\Http\Controllers\RequestType' not found**

What is laravel looking for the class in the Controllers folder. Shouldn't UserController inherit the Controller class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `use`s are not inherited.

Comment: Is there any way to include them?

Comment: No, they are local to the file they are in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write a static class and call it by `use`, then one option is to make use of autoload feature of composer, which will enable the class to be used anywhere.

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
          "app/Lib"
        ]
    },
```

Then in any controller

```
use RequestType;
```

then

```
dd(RequestType::test());
```

Note: Function test should be like

```
public static function test()
```

Comment: But I would still need to include it in every controller. Say I have 50 controllers, I would need to include it in all of them. Sucks that the Controller class can't do this.

Comment: Aren't you going to include the function in every controller?

Comment: I need to include it in every controller, as each controller method will make an api request. What I wish to avoid is the need to write "use RequestType" in each controller. Also, tried the mentioned above, and it said that RequestType class doesn't exist. Any idea why?

Comment: If you want to avoid use then mention entire path ie ```dd(\App\Lib\RequestType::test());```

Comment: If you are giving full path then no need to use ```autoload``` in composer and no need of ```use```.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to auto-magically have a class everywhere.**

PHP `use` is not inherited by extending classes. Even Laravel's Facades have to specified.

You can store the class in the `App\Http\Controllers\Controller->__contruct()` to make it more easily manageable.

```
// App\Http\Controllers\Controller
public function __construct()
{
    $this->requestType = new RequestType();
}

// App\Http\Controllers\FooController
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__contruct();
}

public function index()
{
    $requestType = $this->requestType;
}
```

Comment: @RyanVincent Properly loaded and namespaced classes are accessible via `use` or direct call (e.g. `new App\SomeClass`) but they are not injected into the controller classes. This can only be achieved by modifying how the service container is constructed.